# Conflict with Widget function

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, require, conflicting-libraries

Here is my code for register widget Sidebar

// Sidear Register

```
add_action('widgets_init', 'comet_sidebar');

function comet_sidebar() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('Right Sidebar', 'comet'),
        'description'   => __('Put Right Sidebar here', 'comet'),
        'id'            => 'right-sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h6 class="upper">',
        'after_title'   => '</h6>',
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('Footer Left', 'comet'),
        'description'   => __('Put Footer Sidebar here', 'comet'),
        'id'            => 'footer-left',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="col-sm-4"><div class="widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h6 class="upper">',
        'after_title'   => '</h6>',
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('Footer Right', 'comet'),
        'description'   => __('Put Footer Sidebar here', 'comet'),
        'id'            => 'footer-right',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="col-sm-4"><div class="widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h6 class="upper">',
        'after_title'   => '</h6>',
    ));

}
```

And here is my another php files. I have required

```
if( file_exists( dirname(__FILE__). '/gallery.php' ) ) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__). '/gallery.php' );
}
```

Code for gallery.php

```
<?php


add_shortcode('gallery', 'comet_gallery');

function comet_gallery($attr, $content) {
    $att = shortcode_atts( array(
        'ids' => '',
    ), $attr);          

    extract($att);

    $idd = explode(',', $ids);

    ob_start(); ?>
    <div data-options="{&quot;animation&quot;: &quot;slide&quot;, &quot;controlNav&quot;: true" class="flexslider nav-outside">
        <ul class="slides">
            <?php foreach($idd as $id) : ?>
            <?php $musa = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'full'); ?>

            <li><img src="<?php echo $musa [0]; ?>"></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <?php return ob_get_clean();

}
```

When I required this file. My widget setting don't working correctly. If I remove this require file. It's working perfectly.
Thanks

Comment: what do you have in gallery.php?And what happening exactly?Only widget settings are not working correctly or do you get any blank / broken page?

Comment: I have added code of gallery.php

Comment: I just edited my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that `return ob_get_clean();` is correct.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
add_shortcode('gallery', 'comet_gallery');

function comet_gallery($attr, $content) {
    $att = shortcode_atts( array(
        'ids' => '',
    ), $attr);          

    extract($att);

    $idd = explode(',', $ids);
 ?>
    <div data-options="{&quot;animation&quot;: &quot;slide&quot;, &quot;controlNav&quot;: true" class="flexslider nav-outside">
        <ul class="slides">
            <?php foreach($idd as $id) : ?>
            <?php $musa = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'full'); ?>

            <li><img src="<?php echo $musa [0]; ?>"></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <?php return $content;

}
function comet_gallery_start() { ob_start("comet_gallery"); }
function comet_gallery_end() { ob_end_flush(); }
add_action('wp_head', 'comet_gallery_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'comet_gallery_end');
```

and

```
require_once( TEMPLATEPATH."/gallery.php" );
```